# Support Ticketing module - clients

Tags: 7, users

I want to use the [Support Ticketing System](https://drupal.org/project/support) module to create a 'help desk' for my site. However, I'm not really sure I understand the 'client' system. All I really need is for the user to be able to submit a support ticket to a department, like 'Pre-Sales' or 'Bug Report', and for a member of staff to be able to respond to their issue. I'm just wondering if the support ticket module is 'overkill' and I could code something more simple?

Or, should I just add each department as a client and let users pick which department they'd like that way?

I was using osTicket and was content with it, however I need a user-login system and all the details are already on the drupal site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of "Support Client" as entity that pays for support. Or would pay if you'd charge. On your site you probably want two support clients: your company and external. Or, if you are B2B company, each of your client business should be defined as a support client, plus one for your own company. Then you can tie roles with support clients, like "marketing department" and "sales manager" are roles that belongs to "internal" support client, and "*example company representative*" belongs to "*example support*" support client.

Benefit of this is: all your internal roles can participate in your internal issues, and all roles of one of your clients can participate in theirs, but clients cannot peek at each other's support tickets, or at your internal ones.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification - it has helped. So, is there anyway to let the clients pick a department or is the idea that the correct department is determined once the ticket is submitted and assigned to the ticket by us?